# Using of Interlocked.Exchange for updating of references and Int32

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

It is known that a reference takes 4 Bytes of memory in 32 bit processor and 8 Bytes - in 64 bit processor. So, processors guarantee that single reads from and writes to memory in increments of the natural word size of the machine will be carried out atomically.
On the other hand there are 2 methods in Interlocked class:

```
public static int Exchange(
    ref int location1,
    int value
)
```

and

```
public static T Exchange<T>(
    ref T location1,
    T value
)
where T : class
```

So, the question is why Interlocked.Exchange is needed for Int32 and for reference types?
Couldn't it be done safely by just using of simple assignment because it is atomic?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not only about atomicity. It is also about memory visibility. Variable can be stored in main memory or in CPU cache. If the variable is only stored in CPU cache it will not be visible to threads running on different CPU. Consider following example:

```
public class Test {
    private Int32 i = 5;

    public void ChangeUsingAssignment() {
        i = 10;
    }

    public void ChangeUsingInterlocked() {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref i, 10);
    }

    public Int32 Read() {
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref i, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Now if you call 'ChangeUsingAssignment' on one thread and 'Read' on another thread the return value may be 5, not 10. But if you call ChangeUsingInterlocked, 'Read' will return 10 as expected.

```
 ----------         ------------         -------------------
|   CPU 1  |  -->  |   CACHE 1  |  -->  |                   |
 ----------         ------------        |                   |
                                        |        RAM        |
 ----------         ------------        |                   |
|   CPU 2  |  -->  |   CACHE 2  |  -->  |                   |
 ----------         ------------         -------------------
```

In the diagram above 'ChangeUsingAssignement' method may result in value 10 get 'stuck' in CACHE 2 and not make it to RAM. When CPU 1 later tries to read it, it will get the value from RAM where it is still 5. Using Interlocked instead of ordinary write will make sure that value 10 gets all the way to the RAM.

Comment: I know this is obviously a year later, but if possible, could you please review this? This website http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/ seems to imply that all writes in C# are already volatile.

Comment: You are right about memory visibility but your explanation is not correct. Once the value enters in processor cache it is visible to all physical CPU cores. This is guaranteed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence.

The problem with the memory visibility is when the values are still in read/write buffers inside the CPU core (which is not CPU L1,L2,L3 cache)

Answer (score 10):

`Interlocked.Exchange` has a return value, allowing you to know what value you just replaced. It's the combination of setting a new value *and* obtaining the old value that these methods achieve.

Comment: So if you don't need the old value you could simply assign, but then you'd also need a Barrier call to invalidate the cache(s).

Comment: @Henk: Could you please give more details what do you mean by a Barrier call?

Comment: @Henk: I am soory, but nothing about Barrier call there: http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Barrier+call+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.albahari.com%2Fthreading%2F&hl=uk&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images Could you give some example?

Comment: @gorik: It's part 4 and the full name is MemoryBarrier. But don't go that way.

Answer (score 6):

Exchanging a memory value and the contents of a CPU register is in general not atomic. You both need to read and write the memory location. Furthermore, the `Interlocked` methods guarantees that the operation is atomic even on multi-core computers where each core has its own cache and potentially its own view of the main memory.

Comment: But if I do not need to have old value and want just assign new value to some variable. This is only writing and atomic, right?

Comment: @OlegDudnyk I think it is not correct, even you don't care about original value. Consider how to achieve that in assembly language, depends on where your src and dest variable/value are, they could be translated into more than one instructions, between 2 instructions your application still can get interrupted. On some architectures you can lock the bus to make sure no one can read write memory (e.g. IA has LOCK prefix), and some instructions are guaranteed to be atomic (e.g. XCHG, CMPXCHG, etc,. on IA).

Answer (score 6):

`Interlock.Exchange` returns the *original* value while performing an atomic operation. The whole point is to provide a locking mechanism. So it is actually *two* operations: read original value *and* set new value. Those two together are not atomic.

Comment: But if I do not need to have old value and want just assign new value to some variable. This is only writing and atomic, right?

Comment: @gorik: If it is a read or write operation on a variable of any reference type, or any built-in value type that takes up four bytes or less (for a 32 bit machine) then yes, it is guaranteed to be atomic. Check this series of posts by Eric Lippert on the subject, they will be of some help: [Atomicity, volatility and immutability are different, part one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/26/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-one.aspx)